# Javascript global issues in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am getting 2 error referring to `app.js` file in laravel and no clue why?

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

   `refer to:`
   `<script>
           $(function () {
               $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
           });
   </script>`
2. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`

   `refer to:`
   `function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
           if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
               throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); //here
           }
       }`

PS: `app.js` file will create and combine all assets from node.js.

## Question

How can I fix this?

Comment: Global or Goal issues?

Comment: global :) ............

Comment: Are you adding the `jquery` script before that piece of code?

Comment: @JaimeRojas jquery is added to `app.js` file by laravel default from `package.json`

Comment: @mafortis Your error message would tell a different story. I'd suggest checking your browser's developer console to check what has loaded and in what order.